# How to mock a public method inside a final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to mock a public method inside a final class . My problem is that as I am not able to create the object of that final class , I am not able to spy it . Below is the method inside my class .

```
public final class Method extends Executable {
 @CallerSensitive
    public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
           InvocationTargetException
    {
        if (!override) {
            if (!Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(clazz, modifiers)) {
                Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
                checkAccess(caller, clazz, obj, modifiers);
            }
        }
        MethodAccessor ma = methodAccessor;             // read volatile
        if (ma == null) {
            ma = acquireMethodAccessor();
        }
        return ma.invoke(obj, args);
    }
}
```

I am using powermockito for doing my unit test . I used `PowerMockito.spy(Method.class);` for spying the same , but its not working .

Comment: Is there a reason why this class has to be *final*? If you can't avoid that class being *final*: why don't you have an *Interface* providing the method you want to mock? - Also please read Powermocks (or Mockitos) documenation about the difference between `mock()` and `spy()`

Comment: @TimothyThis class is a library class . I am trying to mock this because of I am calling webservice from here .

Comment: *"This class is a library class"* no reason for `final` IMHO, except is is not under your control...